# Adding a prefix to code sent via Verify API

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I wanted to ask, if it is possible to send out codes with a prefix, eg: Google SMS pin codes "**G -** 123456". We were able to implement one-time-password functionality via the Verify API but we were also asked to add a prefix. Couldn't find anything about that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask what the use-case for an alpha prefix to the code is?

Comment: It is going to be used on a website where a potential buyer can request to be called by an agent. In order to verify that the request is placed by a real person, we are planning to facilitate Twilio's Verify API. Our customer wanted to add their initial letter as a prefix to the code.

Comment: Ok, we have a [template feature](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/templates) coming soon, that would allow you to change the text around the code. It’s currently in pilot, so not available to all yet, but you can contact sales to talk about getting it enabled. This would not change the actual code that needed to be entered (ie it would not be valid with the prefix) but you could handle that on your server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add an alpha prefix, if you have Twilio generate the 2FA code. Your Twilio account team can enable custom 2FA codes on your account to allow for this, but there are some drawbacks, including how verifications are charged.

[Customization Options](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/customization-options)